# How to append an element into array inside a firestore document?

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I'm new in firestore functions and database, so I'm kind of stuck. I have this document:

[image: Database Document]

As you can see, answers in an empty array for now, but I'll have a bunch of string.

The problem is the Cloud Function I'm using is failing. this is my function

```
exports.registerUserResponse = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {

    const original = request.body;
    const type_form_id = original.form_response.form_id

    var userRef = admin.firestore().collection('users').doc(user_email);

    var transaction = admin.firestore().runTransaction(t => {
        return t.get(userRef)
          .then(doc => {
            console.log(doc.data());
            var newAnswer = doc.data().answers.arrayUnion(type_form_id);
            t.update(userRef, {answers: newAnswer});
          });
    }).then(result => {
        //return response.status(200).send();
        return response.status(200).json({result: `Message added.`}).send();
    }).catch(err => {
        console.log(err);
        return response.status(500).json({result: `Message: ${err} error.`}).end();
    });
```

All the values are okay, but I'm getting this error at arrayUnion funtion

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'arrayUnion' of undefined
at t.get.then.doc (/user_code/index.js:27:58)
at process._tickDomainCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:135:7)
```

So, I don't know how I should use that function. Thanks for any answers!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

arrayUnion isn't a method that exists on any item of data you can get back from a Firestore query.  It's definitely not available on the value of undefined that you're getting in `doc.data().answers`.

It looks like you might be confused about how to use [FieldValue.arrayUnion()](https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/docs/reference/firestore/1.2.x/FieldValue#.arrayUnion).  You don't need a transaction to use that.  Just perform an update as described in the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/manage-data/add-data#update_elements_in_an_array):

```
var washingtonRef = db.collection('cities').doc('DC');

// Atomically add a new region to the "regions" array field.
var arrUnion = washingtonRef.update({
  regions: admin.firestore.FieldValue.arrayUnion('greater_virginia')
});
```

Yours might look something like this:

```
admin.firestore().collection('users').doc(user_email).update({
    answers: admin.firestore.FieldValue.arrayUnion(type_form_id)
}).then(...);
```

Comment: Thanks! You were right. This solves the problem. I'm kind of new on this So yeah I was confused jajajaaj